# Turn marginpar into a regular paragraph

Tags: formatting, marginpar, kindle

I'm writing notes for a university course. My content goes into a file called `content.tex` and then use two other files (called `notes.tex` and `kindle.tex`) to define styles and use the LaTeX `import` command to print the content.

This works really well, since I can have two differently formatted `.pdf` files coming from the same source. However, I use the `marginpar` environment in my source quite a lot, and I disabled it for the Kindle formatted output.(to save screen space).

Is there a way to redefine the marginpar environment in my `kindle.tex` so that they appear as regular (or maybe highlighted) paragraphs?

Comment: "Back in the Day" (i.e., the 1700s), they used to flow around margin notes. See, e.g., Teddy Roosevelt's [Winning of the West](https://archive.org/stream/winningwestvolu00unkngoog) for examples...

Comment: @AlexNelson -- Well, sometimes they did, sometimes they [did not](https://archive.org/stream/declineandfallof01gibb#page/6/mode/2up).  What one should do today depends on what effects one is trying to achieve (not that I think you were being prescriptive about `\marginpar` usage).

Comment: @jon For sure! But I was just throwing ideas out there for the OP to consider :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, not too elegant.

```
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]{\par{\bfseries#1}\par}
% or with some vertical extra spaces
% \renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]{\par\medskip{\bfseries#1}\medskip\par}
```

So you can format its content as you wish.

**Default `\marginpar{}`**

[image]

**Redefined `\marginpar{}`**

[image]

Comment: I think it's quite elegant - does the job, short, easy to understand, easy to configure.

Comment: That is a good solution. The only improvement I can think of is for it to align itself with the bottom of the next paragraph, is that possible?

Comment: Are you talking about the default definition? The place or the margin note depends where you insert the command.

Comment: Yes, however, since there are two different `.pdf` files being produced (notes.pdf and kindle.pdf) ideally, I'd want different marginpar placement on them. In the notes file, I'd have the marginpars where they're supposed to be, while in the kindle file they'd be at the end of the paragraph (in line with the main body of the text).

Comment: @ToddDavies, so, remove the first `\par` and no paragraph will be created. But you'll need to insert the note command at the end of the paragraph. If you wish you can try to replace it by `\hfill` to push the note to end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I eventually used, it uses the `tcolorbox` package and produces a box around the margin paragraph:

```
% Make margin paragrahs inline
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!5,colframe=white!40!black,title=Note:]
#1
\end{tcolorbox}}
```

The end result is something like:

[image]